# Ajust height of one or more <span> in a cell of table

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-tables

In this example, is possible to autofit `<span class="orange">ORANGE</span>` to set the largest row height? And with two or more  `<span>` will be possible to split the cell to adjust the heights?

(Now use: display: table, table-row, table-cell, but also could use a classic table)

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/EjqL8/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.table {
  display: table;
  background: #eee;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.cell span {
    display: block;
}

.cell span.red {
    background: red;
}
.cell span.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
.cell span.green {
    background: green;
}
.cell span.orange {
    background: orange;
}
.cell span.grey {
    background: grey;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Header</div>
        <div class="cell">Header</div>
        <div class="cell">Header</div>
        <div class="cell">Header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Row 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Row 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Row 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Row 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <span class="red">RED</span>
            <span class="yellow">YELLOW</span>
            <span class="green">GREEN</span>
            <span class="orange">ORANGE</span>
            <span class="grey">GREY</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">Row 2</div>
        <div class="cell">Row 2</div>
        <div class="cell">
            <span class="orange">ORANGE</span>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <span class="red">RED</span>
            <span class="yellow">YELLOW</span>
            <span class="green">GREEN</span>
            <span class="orange">ORANGE</span>
            <span class="grey">GREY</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">Row 2</div>
        <div class="cell">Row 2</div>
        <div class="cell">
            <span class="green">GREEN</span>
            <span class="orange">ORANGE</span>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/EjqL8/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row .cell:last-child").has("span").each(function(){
        var counter = $(this).find("span").length;
        var height = $(this).height() / counter;                
        $(this).find("span").css('height', height+'px');        
    });
});
```

Comment: Then replace : `.cell:last-child` by `.cell` ... ?

Comment: @Qt Blue Waffle If I enter more than 1 line in a cell, the height is incorrect, look this example http://jsfiddle.net/EjqL8/7/ Any fix?

Comment: Use `span` instead of `<br>`. Plus it's `<br/>` not `<br>`

Comment: @Qt Blue Waffle This example is to make a calendar, and the <span> are the events. What can I do if a event has 3 lines of lenght? I need a way to insert 2 or 3 lines in the **same** <span>. <br/> is perfect, but the height of cell is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/EjqL8/2/

```
$(".row .cell:last-child").has("span").each(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $(this).find("span").each(function(){
        counter += 1;
    });

    var height = 100 / counter;

    $(this).find("span").css('height', height+'%');        
});
```

But you need to set heights for your cells atleast. This way jQuery will calculate the height for your spans. We can also calculate the height of your calls and set them to make this work.

Comment: But, only works if the span is located in the last cell? I need any place... For example http://jsfiddle.net/fekula/EjqL8/3/

Comment: mmm... @Augus if I remove :last-child will works with the spans in any cell?

Comment: Yea it will, cause your looping it in an each function.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do it. You just have to use :

```
$('.toExpand').each(function(){
    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
    $(this).height(parentHeight);    
});
```

to expand it to the full height of parent.
Then divide the `parentHeight` variable to adjust it.

Here is the code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/EjqL8/5/

Comment: @Lisa-Berlin has a better solution I guess.

Comment: The solution of @Lisa-Berlin is without extra classes

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jA4rY/) by using table tag.

You could just use the `rowspan=n` or `colspan=n` (n=number of columns) to merge the columns.

Comment: No merge, I need all span the same cell.

Comment: Either you do it with span tag or table tag. The appearance remains the same. Anyways I suggested you a simple and easy way which I know.

Comment: Actually the rowspan can't work for the last table row. Knowing the first column contains 5 rows and the last contains only 2, you can't specify rowspan=2.5

Comment: Well that's absolutely correct but we can create empty row make it even i guess so.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't want to seem rude, but your majorly re-inventing the wheel here.

Your going to want to try to use a div height percentage.  However, this won't work until you define a height of the parent.  You could just end up scaling back to one starting height, but it just seems like a terrible way to go.

Comment: It would be possible using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, even with jQuery.. there will need to be a default height set, or else percentages cannot be used.  Using div's and jQuery to reinvent the table seems far out there.  I can be wrong, and have been proven wrong before, I just don't see a need for creating a table with DIV's :)